# Why was the definition of a variable changed during the development of C++11?

Tags: c++, variables, object, reference, c++11

n3035 says:

> A variable is introduced by the declaration of an object. The variable's name denotes the object.

n3090 says:

> A variable is introduced by the declaration of *a reference other than a non-static data member or of* an object. The variable's name denotes *the reference or* object.

I wonder what motivated this change. Does it have to do with rvalue references?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The change was in response to [CWG defect 633](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#633).  The list of changes related to this can be found in [n2993](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2993.html):

> The goal of these changes is to expand the meaning of "variable" to encompass both named objects and references, and to apply the term consistently wherever feasible.

Comment: In my opinion that was one of the most disgusting defects in C++03 :) Sadly the other disgusting one [won't be fixed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#554) by C++0x :(

Comment: So, 25 years after the introduction of references into C++ we can finally say that `Foo& x` is a reference variable without contradicting the standard. "Language design is a slow and painstaking process" :)