# What is the difference between a reference variable and a const pointer variable?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between pointer variable and reference variable in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/difference-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)

This is a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/difference-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)

Is a **reference variable** just another name of const pointer variable? If they are different what is the difference between a variable declared as a reference variable and a variable declared as a const pointer variable?

Comment: Unless you really meant to ask the difference between a pointer and a const pointer this is a duplicate of the question that you linked to.

Comment: This has already been answered in the same question you are referring to. From the first answer, all points hold besides the *can be reassigned*. Possible duplicate of [Difference between pointer variable and reference variable in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/difference-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. The problem is that there is no such thing like **reference variable**. Reference is not a variable at all. It is not an object. It actually has no size at all. It is just alternative name of the original object.

Check this:

```
struct A
{
   int i[5];
};

int main()
{
   std::cout << (sizeof(A&) == sizeof(A)) << std::endl;
   std::cout << (typeid(A&) == typeid(A)) << std::endl;
   return 0;
}

A& has the same size as A
A& has the same type as A
```

Comment: Correct for C++03, but [C++0x introduces the notion of reference variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908834/).

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun:) A reference can not be NULL but a const pointer can be.

Comment: @Chusbad: first reaction too :p

Answer (score 0):

> Is a reference variable just another name of const pointer variable?

No.

> If they are different what is the difference between a variable declared as a reference variable and a variable declared as a const pointer variable?

They are completely different things, and there is not enough room to explain everything you need to know here. Read [this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/references.html). Actually, read the [entire FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/). You'll learn a lot.