# can any one explain the difference

Tags: c++, c++11

n3035 says: (2010-02-16)

> A variable is introduced by the declaration of an object. The variable's 
>       name denotes the object.

n3090 says: (2010-03-29)

> A variable is introduced by the declaration of a reference other than a 
>       non-static data member or of an object. The variable's name denotes the 
>       reference or object.

n3242 says: (2011-02-28)

> A variable is introduced by the declaration of a reference other than a 
>       non-static data member or of an object. The variable's name denotes the 
>       reference or object.

CAN any one explain the difference interms (or) with the help of an program(exactly what it say's)

this is the statement from ISO standard C++

I seen this link :

[Why was the definition of a variable changed during the development of C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908834/why-was-the-definition-of-a-variable-changed-in-the-latest-c0x-draft)

but this is not(full meaning) my question ...

Comment: Is there any difference between n3090 and n3242? Why are you listing the oldest (n3035) in the middle?

Comment: re-arranged so they are in order with publish dates.

Comment: Sorry you forgot to list n3035!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider:

```
int x = 42;
int& rx = x;
```

`x` is a variable; should `rx` also be considered a variable?  Many of the Standard's requirements about non-reference variables also apply to references.  It's obviously a pain to have to stipulate "variables or references to variables" constantly throughout the Standard, so if the definition of a variable can include references - perhaps with the occasional "except for references", then the Standard may be - on balance - simplified.  It looks to me like the revisions were exploring this balance.

Answer (score 6):

This was a [`CWG defect #633 in ISO C++03`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#633)

Also check out [`n2993`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2993.html) that deals with `core issue# 633` i.e 
**"Specifications for variables that should also apply to references"**

> > The goal of these changes is to expand the meaning of "variable" to encompass both named objects and references, and to apply the term consistently wherever feasible.

Comment: pleasy explain the difference in terms of program....otherwise Explain the statement n3242 ... in programming way....