# Does reference changes the state of the referent

Tags: c++, reference

As I read

---references are not pointers it is the object itself,A reference is an entity that is an alias for another object.

---references can never represent NULL

---Reference variables allow two variable names to address the same memory location:

---it cannot later be made to refer to a different object

---A reference is not a variable as a variable is only introduced by the declaration of an object. An object is a region of storage and, in C++, references do not (necessarily) take up any storage.

now does the below line **converts the variable integers to a constant integers**

```
const Array& ref = integers
```

furthermore I read [this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/references.html#faq-8.2)
also which says that you can change the state of a referent.

Please suggest/clarify.

Comment: You're missing the type of `ref`. :)

Comment: just to be clear, you are not changing the *state* of the array. You are only changing the *type* that the reference refers to.

Comment: Note that [in C++0x, named references *are* variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908834/).

Comment: yes, it defintitly suggests that refernces are variables. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not convert `integers`. You now just have an alias for `integers` through which you can't change it. You can still change `integers` through the original name:

```
int i = 0;
int const& i_ref = i;
i = 5;
cout << i_ref; // outputs 5
```

The above examble also shows how you can change the state of the referee.

Comment: I was writing a small code and if you have time you can look at [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/232799-overloading-operator-twice-to-represent-a-call-by-rvalue-or-lvalue/)

Comment: @munish: I think you need to read up on how constant member functions work. They are allowed to be called on constant objects while the non-const ones aren't. This is especially useful when passing your dynamic array as a `const Array&` const-reference, because then your `operator[]` (const version) can be called.

Comment: hmm.. i knew that Xeo but I was still confused....anyway I get it now, my problem was this question(on stackoverflow) only...I get it. thanks again..

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the state of a const reference. Apart from that everything you mentioned in there is true.

So for example:

```
const int& ref = integers;
ref = 5;
```

will fail to compile. Where as

```
int& ref = integers;
ref = 5;
```

will compile and it will change the value stored in integers to 5.

Furthermore a const reference means that you cannot change value of the object it refers using the reference. You can still modify it using the original variable name. For example:

```
const int& ref = integers;
integers = 5;
std::cout<<ref<<", "<<integers<<std::endl;
```

is completely valid and will produce:

```
5, 5
```