# Error : non-lvalue in assignment

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Array
{
   friend ostream &operator<<( ostream &, const Array & );
public:
   Array( int = 5 ); 
   Array( const Array & ); 
   ~Array(); 
   int getSize() const; 
   const Array &operator=( const Array & );
   // subscript operator for non-const objects returns modifiable lvalue
   int &operator[]( int );              
   // subscript operator for const objects returns rvalue
   int operator[]( int ) const;  
private:
   int size; 
   int *ptr; 
}; 

Array::Array( int arraySize )
{
   size = ( arraySize > 0 ? arraySize : 5 ); // validate arraySize
   ptr = new int[ size ]; 

   for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
      ptr[ i ] = 0; 
}

// must receive a reference to prevent infinite recursion
Array::Array( const Array &arrayToCopy ) 
   : size( arrayToCopy.size )
{
   ptr = new int[ size ]; // create space for pointer-based array

   for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
      ptr[ i ] = arrayToCopy.ptr[ i ]; // copy into object
} 

Array::~Array()
{
   delete [] ptr; // release pointer-based array space
} 

int Array::getSize() const
{
   return size; // number of elements in Array
} 

const Array &Array::operator=( const Array &right )
{
   if ( &right != this ) // avoid self-assignment
   {
      if ( size != right.size )
      {
         delete [] ptr; // release space
         size = right.size; // resize this object
         ptr = new int[ size ]; // create space for array copy
      }

      for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
         ptr[ i ] = right.ptr[ i ]; // copy array into object
   }

   return *this; 
}

// overloaded subscript operator for non-const Arrays reference return creates a modifiable lvalue
int &Array::operator[]( int subscript )
{
cout << " ***************Inside non-sonstant operator[] function: Lvalue test*********** ";
   if ( subscript < 0 || subscript >= size )
   {
      cerr << "\nError: Subscript " << subscript 
         << " out of range" << endl;
      exit( 1 ); // terminate program; subscript out of range
   }

   return ptr[ subscript ]; // reference return
}

// overloaded subscript operator for const Arrays const reference return creates an rvalue
int Array::operator[]( int subscript ) const
{
cout << " ***************Inside sonstant operator[] function: Rvalue test*********** ";
   if ( subscript < 0 || subscript >= size )
   {
      cerr << "\nError: Subscript " << subscript 
         << " out of range" << endl;
      exit( 1 ); 
   } 

   return ptr[ subscript ]; // returns copy of this element
}


// overloaded output operator for class Array 
ostream &operator<<( ostream &output, const Array &a )
{
   int i;
   // output private ptr-based array 
   for ( i = 0; i < a.size; i++ )
   {
      output << a.ptr[ i ] << " ";

      if ( ( i + 1 ) % 4 == 0 )
         output << endl;
   } // end for

   if ( i % 4 != 0 ) 
      output << endl;

   return output; 
} 

int main()
{
   Array integers1( 4 ); 
   Array integers2; // 5-element Array by default
   const Array& integers4=integers1;
    //integers4[3] = 2000; //Error : non-lvalue in assignment 
    integers1 = integers1;  //valid
    integers4 = integers1;  //Error : binary '=' : no operator found 
    //which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Array' (or there is no 
    //acceptable conversion)
    cout << "\nintegers1[3] is " << integers4[ 3 ];

   return 0;
}
```

Gives errors :

**1)**
In function `int main()':

'=' : left operand must be l-value

**2)**
binary '=' : no operator found 
        which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Array' (or there is no 
        acceptable conversion)

Please help.

Comment: By the way you asked a question about const references a few hours ago  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077332/does-reference-changes-the-state-of-the-referent/6077369#6077369). Please read through all the responses, as others went through a lot of trouble explaining exactly this.

Comment: He modified the original variable.

Comment: No this is not my homework..sorry about trouble

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot modify a const reference, Try this:

```
//Snippet1
Array& integers4=integers1;
integers4[3] = 2000;
```

To  clarify OP's doubt about modifying const references:

```
//Snippet2
//This will not compile as you saw.
const Array& integers4=integers1;
integers4[3] = 2000; //errors
```

Now this is what Xeo did in his reply to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077332/does-reference-changes-the-state-of-the-referent/6077369#6077369). He did not change the reference, but instead the original variable.

```
//Snippet2
//This will compile and work identically to Snippet1.
const Array& integers4=integers1;
interger1[3] = 2000;
```

Comment: I had to post my code because --> see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077332/does-reference-changes-the-state-of-the-referent)

Comment: I think there's another subtle bug. The (const) copy-assignment operator that @munish has written is not in effect, which is probably not what @munish expects. Shouldn't we also recommend dropping const from `const Array &Array::operator=( const Array &right )` as otherwise the compiler-provided default will be in effect?

Comment: @Aaron, you are right, I did not notice it earlier because I was focusing on the compiler errors. Please go ahead and post about it so that you get credit for it.

Comment: But thinking further about it, I think it might be OK :-) Imagine there were three consts (not just two) in `const Array &operator=( const Array & ) const;`   The last const is unacceptable, as it can't even modify itself. The second const is good, as is stops the source item being modified.   It's the first const that I'm unsure of. The first const will cause `a = b = c` not to work as expected, but `b = c` will be OK?  (Therefore, I have decided not to post anything yet.)

Answer (score 2):

First error - `integers4` is a const `Array` so you can only use the `const` `operator[]` which returns `int` rather than `int&`. you cannot assign to a returned temporary `int`, nor should you be able to change something that is a const.
The second error is probably a derivative of the first.

Answer (score 1):

On the particular pieces of code:

```
Array integers1( 4 ); 
const Array& integers4=integers1;
//integers4[3] = 2000; //Error : non-lvalue in assignment
```

You are using a constant reference to an array to call a member function, and the compiler will resolve the call to `int Array::operator[]( int x ) const` (the other version of `operator[]` requires a non-const object). The expression yields an rvalue and you cannot assign to it.

```
integers4 = integers1;  //Error : binary '=' : no operator found
```

Again the issue is that `integers4` is a constant lvalue, and that means that it cannot be modified (because of the `const` in there).

Comment: finally something gets into my thick skull